# WCF service throws exception but client never receives it

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Inside my wcf service I have method exposed to the service client. This method is decorated with FaultContract attribute so I can return and catch custom exception.

inside IBookService I have

```
 [FaultContract(typeof(BookServiceAuthorizeFault))]
 [OperationContract]
 IEnumerable<string> GetAllBookTitlesFromSpecificGenre(string genre);
```

That custom typed fault is wrapped inside

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class BookServiceAuthorizeFault
{
   private string _Message;
   public BookServiceAuthorizeFault(string message)
   {
      _Message = message;        
   }

   [DataMember]
   public string Message 
   {
      get { return _Message;  }
      set { _Message = value; }
   }
 }
```

Insude Service which implements this interface I on purpose throwing exception

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAllBookTitlesFromSpecificGenre(string genre)
{
   throw new FaultException<BookServiceAuthorizeFault>(new BookServiceAuthorizeFault("Unauthorize access"));    
}
```

and finally on client side I want to catch this exception

```
catch (FaultException<BookServiceAuthorizeFault> bsaf)
{
     MessageBox.Show(bsaf.Message);
}
```

but I this catch block is never hitted, I'm getting unhandled user exception at service side
on   `public IEnumerable<string> GetAllBookTitlesFromSpecificGenre(string genre)`

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your solution should be working as expected if you change debugging settings inside visual studio.

Go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Debugging` -> `General` and uncheck "`Enable the exception assistant`".